# MVC post losing values when submitted via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC form with a submit button:

```
 <form method="POST" id="submitProject" action="@Url.Action(SubmitProject, "ProjectSummary")">
                <button type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitProject" value="saveToProposed" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Project</button>
            </form>
```

But when a user clicks on that button i want to show them a confirmation dialog before the post goes on its way:

```
 $('#submitProject').submit(function (e) {
        var currentForm = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Approve or Reject",
            title: "Project Approval",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Approve",
                    className: "btn-success",
                    callback: function () {
                        alert("Approved");
                        currentForm.submit();
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "Reject",
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function () {
                        alert("Rejected");
                        currentForm.submit();
                    }
                },
                main: {
                    label: "Cancel",
                    className: "btn-primary",
                    callback: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

in my controller i am trying to trap the value of the submit button like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitProject(ProjectModel m, string submitButton)
        {
}
```

if i do not have that preventDefault line in there i can see the value of the submitButton in the controller. With the preventDefault the value is always null.
this is something i have been struggling with for some time as i try to learn MVC. if i didn't have any client side interaction i would be fine. But trying to get js to play with mvc is giving me hearburn. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: A submit buttons value is only posted back when that submit button is clicked. You are cancelling the default action and calling `currentForm.submit();` which will not include the value of the submit button.

Comment: that makes sense. but what recourse do i have? i have multiple submit buttons on this form and i need to know which was clicked, but i also need that confirm dialog

Comment: You can just handle the `.submit()` event but in the function call `return false` if you want to cancel it (i.e if the 'Cancel' button is clicked) or `return true` to let the normal submit happen (and remove `e.preventDefault();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form only posts back the name/value pair of its submit button that was clicked. In your case your cancelling the buttons `.click()` event and then calling the `.submit()` function (i.e. the submit is no longer triggered by the click so its value is not sent in the request).

Rather than calling `e.preventDefault();`, call a function that returns `true` or `false`, in the same way that you can use the javascript `.confirm()` function to cancel the form submission (i.e. `return confirm("...");`

```
function confirmSubmit()
{
    bootbox.dialog({
        ....
        // for the success and danger buttons - return true;
        // for the main button - return false

        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Approve",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            ....
    });
}

$('#submitProject').submit(function (e) {
    return confirmSubmit();
});
```

Side note: your form only has one submit button, so the value of `string submitButton` will only ever be `"saveToProposed"`. Not sure if you omitted it from your code, but I assume you would really have at least 2 submit buttons.